# Rename while Compiling fromTerminal

Tags: compiling

General Question,

is there a way to rename the pdf output while compiling through the terminal.

i know i can create the file then rename it, but i am looking for a way that is built into latex

Comment: You can use `pdflatex --jobname=mynewname file`

Comment: this is causing my file to pop-up a warning: LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right. i will be creating a way to manage that and run the command again, but i want to have this error as less as possible

Comment: You will have to run again (and also other tools like bibtex with the new jobname). A new jobname leads to new auxiliary files with this names. If you don't want this you will have to rename if after the normal compilation with the suitable terminal command.